# Insert the data from excel to table if data not already not existed, if existed the write to file in SSIS 2005

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005, insert, ssis, lookup

I'm new to SSIS. I'm trying to load the data from the excel to sql server table.  What i have to do if the data already existed in the table then I have write it to a temp table or file if not existed then I have to insert into the table.

We are using sql server 2005. I'm using look up transformation to achieve that. But its not working. Is there any can I achieve it.

Please suggest me some tips. Your help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
VG.

Answer (score 0):

I would write down the conceptual steps - as opposed to giving the step-by-step solution. This in my opinion be more helpful in developing the understanding. If you get stuck on any step, please let us know.

Step 1:

First of all load the file into a temporary table. You do not need to create the table manually; let BIDS create it for you. Alter the table to add a new column - ALREADY_EXISTS - BIT data type.

You would need to use Data Flow Task. Within it, use Excel data source and ADO destination.

Step 2a:
Write a sql statement in SSMS using inner join on your temp table and the final destination table. Make sure that the query you come up with gives the result you are expecting. Use this SELECT statement to UPDATE the ALREADY_EXISTS column inside the temp table.

Step 2:
Put Execute SQL task on the control surface. Use the query from Step 2.

Step 3:
Put another DFT on the control surface. Write a plain SELECT statement to pick up all columns - include the ALREADY_EXISTS.

Use a conditional split to determine new and existing records and point them accordingly to their destination.

Also, read up on Merge statement which is a feature introduced in SQL Server 2008.

Please share your experience with this solution.